# Featureplot by co-expression of some genes

Tags: r, scrnaseq, seurat

I want to identify `MDSCs` cells which don't not express `HLA-DRs` (HLA-DR negative) but express `CD14`, `CD33`, and `ITGAM`

For this, I firstly plotted a feature plot to locate `HLA-DR` by

```
cd.features <- list(grep(pattern = '^HLA-DR', x = rownames(x = pbmc_small), value = TRUE))

pbmc_small <- AddModuleScore(object = pbmc_small, features = cd.features, ctrl = 5, name = 'CDFeatures')


FeaturePlot(object = pbmc_small, features = 'CDFeatures1')& 
+     scale_colour_gradientn(colours = rev(brewer.pal(n = 11, name = "RdBu")))
```

Which returned

[image]

For `CD14`, `CD33`, and `ITGAM` I done

```
> cd.features=list(c("CD14", "CD33",  "ITGAM"))
> pbmc_small <- AddModuleScore(object = pbmc_small, features = cd.features, ctrl = 5, name = 'CDFeatures')
> FeaturePlot(object = pbmc_small, features = 'CDFeatures1')& 
+     scale_colour_gradientn(colours = rev(brewer.pal(n = 11, name = "RdBu")))

>
```

Which returned

[image]

By looking at these two plots I really can not say which part of plot is HLA-DR negative but expressing `CD14`, `CD33`, and `ITGAM`

Do you know a way to do this?

Plotting options don't help because looking at the below plots you can not say which cells are HLA negative and CD14 positive

[image]

[image]

Comment: Will the user who flagged for this post to be closed please add a comment stating why they think this post should be closed? I don't see any problem with it.

Comment: My small comment, I'd simply use ggplot2 if I was using R (not hugely helpful). It is a lot more powerful though. @RamRS point: It is a very clear question, nicely presented on a good subject. I can make a good educated guess why someone did this, but its really for meta. Closing questions is a current topic there. It is unlikely the question will be closed - its just a vote. (For the record I upvoted.)

Comment: @haci will know this, but will have to get into cellular immunology.

Comment: Thinking about it you really want a third axis and a good viewing angle. Plotly might be a better option than featurePlot. Interesting but not my thing.

Answer (score 2):

Very old question, but recently modified, which means that someone might still be looking into this.

I usually prefer to use [Ucell](https://github.com/carmonalab/UCell) as the signatures are calculated within cells, which makes comparisons a bit easier. In addition is allows the formulation of signatures with both `positive` and `negative` genes.

```
hladr_genes <- grep(pattern = '^HLA-DR', x = rownames(x = pbmc_small), value = TRUE)
signatures_list <- list(MDSCs = c("CD14+","CD33+","ITGAM+",paste0(hladr_genes,"-")))

> signatures_list
$MDSCs
[1] "CD14+"     "CD33+"     "ITGAM+"    "HLA-DRA-"  "HLA-DRB5-" "HLA-DRB1-"

# calculate signature
pbmc_small <- AddModuleScore_UCell(pbmc_small,signatures_list,ncores = 8,name = "")
# perform smoothing
pbmc_small <- SmoothKNN(pbmc_small, signature.names = names(signatures_list), reduction="pca")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a transformed variable to the gene sets of interest. I would rescale the data on a range of 0-1. Then you can make a log2 ratio of the sum(set1)/sum(set2). You could explore other transformations, but this will give contrasting values for high set1 and high set2, but neutral if the expression is similar between the sets.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).